# why task is not reusable and service is reusable in javafx concurrency?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have read a tutorial about javafx concurrency.
I have also make demonstration on service and task.
but confuses service is reusable and task is not reusable.

Answer (score 2):

If Task were reusable it would be pretty much identical to a Service because reusability is the major identifying feature of a Service.  The reusability access adds complexity to the API, so if you don't need reusability, just use a Task, and if you do, then use a Service.